# I cannot edit any files (checkout error or user cancellation)

Tags: tfs

I am trying to work on a new project, which is accessed through Team Foundation Server 2008. I don't have any experience in working with tfs, but it seems pretty straight forward what to do. Here is what I did:

1) Tools -> Connect to Team Foundation Server...

2) Select the project, then OK.

3) In Source Control Explorer, I right-click and select "Get specific version..." and choose "Overwrite all files even if the local version matches the specified version", then "Get"

4) Then it asks "Projects have been added to this solution. Do you want to get them from source control?" and I select "Yes".

5) Then there is an error. "Unable to read the project file '...CommonLogic.DocumentUtile.csproj. 'D:...CommonLogic.DocumentUtil.csproj' was not found. I click OK.

6) the project "CommonLogic.DocumentUtils" is now unavailable in the Solution Explorer. It says "The project file cannot be loaded."

Anyway, I don't know if that error is the cause. But when I try to edit any file in the solution (not in the above project), then I get a popup that says: "Checkout error or user cancellation" and a text of the current file stating "File was not checked out".

What is the cause of this? and what can I do about it?

Comment: Ok, never mind. I had to get permissions to the tfs server. That fixed it.

Comment: Answer the question yourself, and accept the answer, then.  That way this will show as a closed answer.

Answer (score 1):

This error will occur when you don't have permissions to the file.